# SNMP-capable temperature probes

Tags: monitoring, snmp, physical-environment

I'm looking for a SNMP temperature monitoring solution to put into my racks. Idealy this thingy would be an ethernet device with SNMP capability. I'd like to put two of these probes as top of rack and bottom of rack probes. No need for a fancy wireless mesh network solution or anything. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

We use Room Alert by [avtech](http://avtech.com/), they have different version that can do humidity, power etc. They are robust and work quite well.

If you only want to do temperature, the TemPageR 3ER look like a good bet. You can add multiple temperature sensors per device.

Comment: We use RoomAlert too, I think ours is an 11E.  Took me a bit to get snmp working against it, but since then it has been set and forget.

Answer (score 0):

These are good;
http://www.zantech.com.au/sensor/sensorprobe.html

Answer (score 0):

APC has some nice environmental products like the [Netbotz 200](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=346) that you can use to plug different sensors into it. It can be checked by SNMP and it also has it's own notifications mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

[ITWatchDogs](http://www.itwatchdogs.com) has a great line of climate and power monitors for almost half the cost of other providers.  You can call 512-257-1462 or e-mail sales@itwatchdogs.com with your requirements and we can help you find products that are right for you.

Also note that all technical support is handled by the same programmers and engineers that develop and maintain ITW products so rest assured of receiving proper tech support when you need it most.

Feel free to e-mail me at msheikh@itwatchdogs.com with any questions.

Regards,
Mo @ ITWatchDogs